# How to use Django with PGBouncer?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pgbouncer

I have an application launched in Django, which has a very high traffic of requests and queries to the databases. I am having problems and I have read that with PGBouncer and some settings in Django I can solve the problem.

The question is how to integrate PGBouncer with Django.

1. I have the Django application in Docker.
2. The database is Postgres and it is in the RDS service of Amazon web services.
3. Would PGBouncer be installed on the instance where the Django application runs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: What problem are you having that you think pgbouncer might solve?